# Rewrite URL or Redirect URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, drupal, url-rewriting

I have a domain running with Two CMS. One is Drupal and other is WordPress.
Say Drupal will load with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and WordPress will load as [www.example.com/wp](http://www.example.com/wp)

Now i want a URL which is running as [www.example.com/wp/app](http://www.example.com/wp/app) should load as [www.example.com/app](http://www.example.com/app)

What should i do?

URL rewrite or URL redirect?

If URL rewrite can someone help me with the condition?

Comment: You need a RewriteRule to map `/app` to `/wp/app` Try this [RewriteRule generator](https://htaccess.xyz) to create rules.

Comment: I tried Rewriting the URL and many conditions which did not work. So, i ended up setting Redirect.

Redirect /app /wp/app/

Thanks